# Difficulties encountered in using s3a

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-18.04, ceph

I am a newcomer to big data development, and I have encountered some problems that may be very simple and ask for help from the big guys.
I want to test the performance of hadoop accessing ceph through s3a locally, and I did the following:

1. The virtual machine installed 3 Ubuntu18.04 servers and initialized the network and IP, installed
   JDK18, and installed hadoop3.2.2;
2. Password-free login settings,modify hosts and configure nickname;
3. Configured the environment variables of JDK and hadoop, and modified the core-site.xml/hdfs-
   site.xml/mapred-site.xml/hadoop-env.sh in the hadoop3.X/etc/hadoop/ directory.
4. The configuration is pasted as follows：

   ```
       <property>
           <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
           <value>file:/home/program/hadoop/data</value>
           <description>Abase for other temporary directories.</description>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
           <value>hdfs://hadoop04:9000</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>hadoop.http.staticuser.user</name>
           <value>root</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
           <value>ak</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
           <value>sk</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
           <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
           <value>https://172.17.37.60:8080</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled</name>
           <value>false</value>
       </property>

       hdfs-site.xml
       <configuration>
               <property>
       　　　　　　　　<name>dfs.replication</name>
       　　　　　　　　<value>3</value>
       　　　　　　</property>
               <property>
       　　　　　　　　<name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
       　　　　　　　　<value>hadoop04:9870</value>
       　　　　　　</property>
       　　　　　　<property>
       　　　　　　　　<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       　　　　　　　　<value>file:/home/program/hadoop/data/dataname</value>
       　　　　　　</property>
       　　　　　　<property>
       　　　　　　　　<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       　　　　　　　　<value>file:/home/program/hadoop/data/datanode</value>
       　　　　　　</property>
       </configuration>

       mapred-site.xml
       <configuration>
               <property>
       　　　　　　　　<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
       　　　　　　　　<value>hadoop04:9001</value>
       　　　　　　</property>
       </configuration>
   ```
5. Under the premise of not using s3a, it is normal for me to call Hadoop on the client side of Hadoop, and it can operate normally.In order to use s3a,from the website [hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/),I added hadoop-client and hadoop-aws to pom dependencies .
6. My exploration is to put hadoop-client-2.X.jar and hadoop-aws-2.X.jar in the hadoop-3.2.2/share/hadoop/client/ directory of the server. Restart hadoop, and then use the command hadoop fs -ls s3a://endpoint:port ,and I got an Exception

   ````
       java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2638)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3341)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3373)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:125)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3424)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3392)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:485)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:352)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:250)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:233)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.FsCommand.processRawArguments(FsCommand.java:104)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:177)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:327)
           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:390)
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2542)
           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2636)
           ... 16 more```
   ````
7. I know that the reason for the abnormal S3AFileSystem is that the jar package is misplaced. Are there any other problems?

Comment: I'd start with the S3A documentation, here the troubleshooting page https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html

Comment: Yes, I know that this jar package is missing, but where should this package be placed? I put it under hadoop-home/share/hadoop/client and it doesn't take effect.

Comment: 1. you need the matching aws sdk JAR.
2. it's a bit odd with the object store extensions. An env var can add them locally, but that doesn't line them up across the cluster. easiest to add in the same dir as hadoop-common.jar is found

Answer (score 0):

I have added below JARs in hive's lib directory and it worked for me (Hive 3.0)

```
hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar
guava-27.0-jre.jar
aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar
```

Also you can put these jars into different location and add path in hive-env.sh

`export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=<Path to all JAR files>`